# Not getting every value of for loop in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

In angular `for loop` is printing all values in `console`, but printing only the last value on the web page. I want to show all values on the web page.

```
export class RentCalculatorComponent {
    constructor() { }

    rent: any = '';

    increase: any = '';

    months: any = '';

    calculate() {
      for (let i = 1; i <= this.months; i++) {
        this.rent = this.rent + this.rent * this.increase / 100
        console.log(this.rent);
      }
}
```

Comment: A lot of information is missing

Comment: i only want to know how to return every instance of for loop

Comment: By using `*ngFor`, is how you see every instance of your array. You might want to add your template code as well and maybe explain what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular, when you call to a function, the function is executed and, after, repaint the app. it's the reason because after execute the loop, your variable "rent" has the last value and is this value who is showed in the app.

If you want to show all the values, you need use an array and show the array

```
rent: any[] = []; //declare an array

calculate() {
      let rent=0; //use a auxiliar variable
      for (let i = 1; i <= this.months; i++) {
        rent = rent + rent * this.increase / 100;
        this.rent[i] = rent; //here store in the array the result
                             //see that use this.rent[i]
                             //to change the value of the variable "rent"
                             //of the component
        console.log(this.rent[i]);
      }
}
```

And you show using *ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let r of rent;let i=index">
   month {{i+1}} --> {{r}}
</div>
```

To know about [arrays in typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays) or [arrays in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), to know about [ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgFor)